# Ember data - Multiple namespaces for single model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an Ember data model named **Activity**.

Depending on my current route, I need to call services to populate the store with activities from different API namespaces. So while my current **ActivityAdapter** looks like this:

```
App.ActivityAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'services/activities'
});
```

I really want it to look like this:

```
App.ActivityAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    if (this.get('currentRoute') === "user") {
        namespace: 'services/users/activities'
    } else {
        namespace: 'services/activities'
    }
});
```

I can't seem to find a solution for this, and the best I can think of right now is a hack that involves creating a separate **UserActivity** model that basically has the same properties as the **Activity** model, and then specifying a separate **UserActivityAdapter**.

Has anyone else run into this issue? Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Do you control your API on the server? If so, you could simply change your `/services/activities` endpoint to accept an optional `userId` query param.

So you will always target the same namespace:

- `GET /services/activities` => returns all activities
- `GET /services/activities?userId=123` => return activities for user `123`

This is a common pattern in REST APIs. But maybe I misunderstood your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the response! You're absolutely right, but unfortunately I don't have access to the API on the server.